# Is there a way to display a specific Flutter page when screen is locked?

Tags: flutter, dart

please is there a way to display or open a Flutter page when screen is locked in Flutter like how WhatsApp displays incoming call page when screen is locked? I used Wake up plugin but can't display the page on screen locked. Please I need a guide to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a [time sensitive notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive) with a [full screen notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder). What it does is that if the screen is locked it opens the activity linked to the pending intent used for full screen notification. When the phone is unlocked, it shows a heads up notification instead. You must have seen this behavior with all kinds of telephony apps and alarm apps.

A flutter app runs inside a single activity, so if you mark that as the activity to show during the locked state, the app will show. But it will act similar to how the app would when you launch it from start. Also the behavior is unpredictable as it is behind a wakelock. So a better option would be to move it to a separate activity and do the needful. Example of how to implement full screen notifications.

https://medium.com/android-news/full-screen-intent-notifications-android-85ea2f5b5dc1

Comment: Wow thanks! @Chinmay Kabi. I will try out this method and get back to you for feedback. Thanks once again!!